# dip-in -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Context:

> In this chapter, yet more core CSS knowledge has been thrown at you, much of which forms the
>   bulk of all the CSS development you’ll do from now on. Grasping this basic knowledge of layout
>   approaches will stand you in good stead for what is to follow. If you are not sure you’ve understood everything in the first three chapters, fear not. So long as you don’t tear them out, they’ll remain in place as a **dip-in** guide should you need to refresh your memory.

What does that adjective mean as used in that paragraph?

Comment: "[Dip into something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/dip-into)" could mean "to read, watch, or listen to small amounts of something such as a piece of writing or a program". I believe that the author used it as an adjective to mean that it's a guide that you can dip into anytime at your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dip in** as in "`dip your foot into a pool of water`". It would mean a gentle (re)introduction to it.

The opposite of this would be to 'throw you into the deep end'.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the meaning is the same as:

> ...they’ll remain in place as a **quick reference** guide should you need to refresh your memory.

Answer (score 0):

The adj dip-in is rarely found in use. Nor can we find it in a dicionary.
It seems that the word has been minted like the words we have in use such as drop-in, drive-in, etc. I think it means that it'll serve as a guide you can browse through and get some knowledge, if not thorough.